# Vertical gradient line or a shape in unordered list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to put a vertical shape with app. 50px height and 15px width, in front of the first two numbers in the scoreboard. I have tried with a span and width/height in css but it does not render, and if I try with " | " it keeps pushing other items out of the center. Is there a way to put a shape in front of the first two numbers that could be customized into gradient later, while preserving the shape/padding/margin of the table rows, avatars, names nicely put one under the other?

So, I want to achieve something like this: http://sketchtoy.com/67287993

But only for first 2-3 items on the list, others would only have to stay in exact order with avatars and other data one under the other.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqdjRd?editors=1100

html:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<body>
  <div class="container">


    <div class="col-md-6 right__column">
      <ul id="table" class="tableList">
        <p class="tableHeader">Scoreboard</p>
        <br>
        <h5 class="tableHeader__user">results</h5>
        <hr class="line">
        <li><span class="gradient">| </span><span class="numbers">1.</span> <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" alt="user" class="avatar"><span class="name"> John Doe</span><span class="numbers__points pull-right">10 points</span> </li>
        <hr class="line">
        <li><span class="numbers">2.</span> <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" alt="user" class="avatar"><span class="name"> John Doe</span><span class="numbers__points pull-right">9 points</span> </li>
        <hr class="line">
        <li><span class="numbers">3.</span> <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" alt="user" class="avatar"><span class="name"> John Doe</span><span class="numbers__points pull-right">8 points</span> </li>
        <hr class="line">
        <li><span class="numbers">4.</span> <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" alt="user" class="avatar"><span class="name"> John Doe</span><span class="numbers__points pull-right">7 points</span> </li>
        <hr class="line">
        <li><span class="numbers">5.</span> <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" alt="user" class="avatar"><span class="name"> John Doe</span><span class="numbers__points pull-right">6 points</span> </li>
        <hr class="line">
        <li><span class="numbers">6.</span> <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" alt="user" class="avatar"><span class="name"> John Doe</span><span class="numbers__points pull-right">7 points</span> </li>
        <hr class="line">
        <li><span class="numbers">7.</span> <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" alt="user" class="avatar"><span class="name"> John Doe</span><span class="numbers__points pull-right">6 points</span> </li>
        <hr class="line line__margin">
        <li class="dots text-center"><span>&bull;&bull;&bull;</span></li>
        <hr class="line line__margin--bottom">
        <li><span class="numbers">100.</span> <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" alt="user" class="avatar"><span class="name"> John Doe</span><span class="numbers__points pull-right">5 points</span> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

css:

```
.right__column {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-right: 36px;
}

.tableHeader {
  font-size: 160%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: white;
}

.tableHeader__user {
  color: white;
  font-size: 110%;
}

.name {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 120%;
}

.tableHeader__points {
  color: red;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 1px;
}

.dots {
  font-size: 280%;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: red;
}

.line {
  color: blue;
  border-color: -moz-use-text-color -moz-use-text-color;
}

.line__margin {
  margin-bottom: -6%;
}

.line__margin--bottom {
  margin-top: -4%;
}

.numbers {
  color: white;
  font-size: 130%;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

.avatar {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.numbers__points {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 125%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.gradient {
  color: yellow;
  height: 50px;
  width: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use gradient to draw something like this and even use less and valid markup.

example

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
.right__column {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 0 0 1em 36px;/* set your own */
  color:white;
  letter-spacing: -1px; 
}
ol {
  border-bottom:1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 36px 0 0;/* set your own */
  padding:0;
  font-size:20px;
}
li {
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
  padding-top:1em;/* set your own */
  margin-bottom:1em;/* set your own */
  list-style-position:inside;
  padding-left:20px;
  background:linear-gradient(blue,white) no-repeat bottom left;/* set your own */
  background-size:15px calc(100% - 1em);/* set your own */
}
li img, li span {
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin:0 0 0 0.5em;
  color:blue;
}
.numbers__points {
  color:inherit;
  line-height:50px;/* because image is 50px tall */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-6 right__column">
    <h1>scoreboards</h1><!-- title is not paragraph ;) -->
    <h2>results</h2><!-- 2 follows 1 -->
    <ol>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" alt="user" class="avatar">
        <span class="name"> John Doe</span>
        <span class="numbers__points pull-right">10 points</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" alt="user" class="avatar">
        <span class="name"> John Doe</span>
        <span class="numbers__points pull-right">10 points</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" alt="user" class="avatar">
        <span class="name"> John Doe</span>
        <span class="numbers__points pull-right">10 points</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" alt="user" class="avatar">
        <span class="name"> John Doe</span>
        <span class="numbers__points pull-right">10 points</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" alt="user" class="avatar">
        <span class="name"> John Doe</span>
        <span class="numbers__points pull-right">10 points</span>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS borders, instead of | character and hrs inside the UL. 
use CSS `:nth-child(n)` sudo-class to select first and 2nd childs (li) of ul.

```
ul#table li {
  border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
}

ul#table li:nth-child(1), ul#table li:nth-child(2){
  border-left:15px solid #cccccc;
  padding-left: 5px
}
```

check here:
http://codepen.io/ramkaldesign/pen/PzZGBg?editors=1100

Comment: Thank you this is really interesting solution..is it possible that the border on the left(15px) does not touch the upper and bottom line, but remains inside them without going too far left?

Comment: To achieve that, the only solution I know is to use a vertical image background for the LIs. Then you need to calculate the height of the LIs exactly and create the background image slightly smaller than the LIs heights. and then set the background position to left (horizontal) and middle (vertical).

Comment: Yes I can't figure it out whole day...to illustrate, this is what I am trying to achieve  http://sketchtoy.com/67287993